# How to query a document with the highest value of a field

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

Let's say I have a collection of documents. To make this simpler, let's say all these documents have just 2 fields, name and id, like below.

I want to get the document with the greatest value of "id". Can I use the .find({}) with some parameters? If so, I can't figure out which parameter would find me the max value of a certain field.

```
[
  {
    name: "name1",
    id: 1
  }
  {
    name: "name2",
    id: 2
  }
  {
    name: "name1",
    id: 3
  }
  {
    name: "name1",
    id: 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let documents = [
  {
    name: "name1",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "name2",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "name1",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "name1",
    id: 0
  }
];

let max = documents.sort( (a, b) => a.id > b.id ? -1 : 1)[0]
console.log( max );
```

How about 
`let maxIdDocument = documents.sort( (a, b) => a.id > b.id ? 1 :  -1)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

First, sort in descending order, then get the first one:

```js
const arr = [{
    name: "name1",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "name2",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "name1",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "name1",
    id: 0
  }
];

const [greatest] = arr.sort(({ id: a }, { id: b }) => b - a);

console.log(greatest);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort that array and with the function `pop` get the object with the greatest `id`.

```
arr.slice() // This is to avoid a mutation on the original array.
```

```js
let arr = [   {     name: "name1",     id: 1   },   {     name: "name2",     id: 2   },   {     name: "name1",     id: 3   } ,  {     name: "name1",     id: 0   } ],
    greatest = arr.slice().sort(({id: a}, {id: b}) => a - b).pop();

console.log(greatest);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```